# How to instantiate Liferay Portlet multiple times

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay, portlet

I'am using JBoss 7.1.1 with Liferay 6.2GA.
I need a portlet instance on each page.
The constructor of the MVCPortlet class is only called after deploying the portlet, so it's just instantiate one time (after deploying).

I tried

```
<instanceable>true</instanceable>
```

in liferay-portlet.xml but this didn't changed anything.

How can I create a new instance of my portlet when I drag the portlet out of the 'add application' menu to place it on a, just for this instance, created page?

In order to control the number of instances, I did:

```
public class Controller extends MVCPortlet {
private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Controller");
private int instance = 0;
public Controller() {
        instance++;
        log.info("instance: " + instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call a constructor on each add?

Comment: I have built the project in the idea that it would be instantiated for each page. I have a special application, in which each user has exactly one page, but the user isn't logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your business to instantiate portlet classes. The portal will do so for you. A portlet has no state in the class: As soon as you have a member variable in your portlet, keeping any personal state, that's a potential problem.

The portal typically will only have a single object for portlets (just like with servlets). *All* of the state that you'd like to add to the portlet itself goes into the request and response objects that are handled during the various lifecycle methods.

Whatever you're attempting that does rely on multiple (java) objects: It's wrong. You *need* to change your architecture

Comment: That is sad for me, but thanks. I don't see the benefits of this kind the portlets works, I mean, a jar can run on mulitple pc's, why can't a portlet run on different pages. Thank you Olaf.

Comment: Of course a portlet can be on multiple pages. It's just that the complete state is not in the portlet object itself, but in the request/response, or in the session. Would you expect to have one object per page, one per user, one per session? What about cluster nodes (different JVMs)? This request doesn't make sense and the implementation doesn't limit you *at all*. It's just how this specification was implemented and there's a clear solution to implement your underlying problem. It's just not the solution that you envisioned.